# WPF giving maximize,minimize,resize control to child window

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

Hosting a child window from different process into my WPF application.
Parent window has WindowStyle = "None".
I want to give control for resize & move to the child window i.e. parent window will maximize, minimize, close, move, resize corresponding to the child window operations.

Answer (score 0):

For each control you can set under **Properties**

> Layout 
>   Anchor  -> Top, Bottom, Left, Right

this will fit your control to  the child : Windows Form , Tabs, etc .